# Generate multiple similar functions with C preprocessor

Tags: c, function, macros, preprocessor

I want to generate multiple similar functions replacing just one word across the function.

As an example, for each of the below:

```
OBJECT = customer
OBJECT = account
```

use the function template:

```
void add_OBJECT_to_array(void* item_ptr, int pos)
{
    mtx_lock(&OBJECT_array_mtx);
    OBJECT_array[pos] = *(OBJECT_t*)item_ptr;
    mtx_unlock(&OBJECT_array_mtx);
    return;
}
```

So that I can call

```
add_order_to_array(ord, 1);
add_customer_to_array(cust, 1);
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Totally possible. You just need to know about the preprocessor concatenation operator `##`. The following code will generate two functions `add_order_to_array` and `add_customer_to_array`.

```
#define GENERATE_FUNC(OBJECT) \
    void add_ ## OBJECT ## _to_array(void* item_ptr, int pos)\
    {                                                        \
        mtx_lock(&OBJECT ## _array_mtx);                     \
        OBJECT ## _array[pos] = *(OBJECT ## _t*)item_ptr;    \
        mtx_unlock(&OBJECT ## _array_mtx);                   \
        return;                                              \
    }                                                      

GENERATE_FUNC(order)
GENERATE_FUNC(customer)
```

The preprocessor output will be (unfortunately it does not respect formatting):

```
void add_order_to_array(void* item_ptr, int pos) { mtx_lock(&order_array_mtx); order_array[pos] = *(order_t*)item_ptr; mtx_unlock(&order_array_mtx); return; }
void add_customer_to_array(void* item_ptr, int pos) { mtx_lock(&customer_array_mtx); customer_array[pos] = *(customer_t*)item_ptr; mtx_unlock(&customer_array_mtx); return; }
```

Comment: should i manually write the function prototypes in the header or should i generate them too?

Comment: @localhost You could generate them too, but with a different macro, e.g. `GENERATE_FUNC_DECL`

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible:

```
#define DECLARE_ADD_FUNCTION(__obj)                         \
    void add_##__obj##_to_array(void* item_ptr, int pos)    \
    {                                                       \
        mtx_lock(&__obj##_array_mtx);                       \
        __obj##_array[pos] = *(__obj##_t*)item_ptr;         \
        mtx_unlock(&__obj##_array_mtx);                     \
        return;                                             \
    }

DECLARE_ADD_FUNCTION(customer)
DECLARE_ADD_FUNCTION(account)
```

When you look at the output of the preprocessor you get:

gcc -E foo.c

```
void add_customer_to_array(void* item_ptr, int pos) { mtx_lock(&customer_array_mtx); customer_array[pos] = *(customer_t*)item_ptr; mtx_unlock(&customer_array_mtx); return; }
void add_account_to_array(void* item_ptr, int pos) { mtx_lock(&account_array_mtx); account_array[pos] = *(account_t*)item_ptr; mtx_unlock(&account_array_mtx); return; }
```

You can even ensure that the pointer type is the correct type by changing the function prototype to `add_##__obj##_to_array(__obj##_t *, int pos)`

Comment: Identifiers starting with `__` are reserved, so I'd choose a different name for the macro parameter.

Comment: — All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces.

In this particular case __obj is scoped within the macro, and is the proper use of __

Comment: If it's scoped to the macro anyway, why not just name it `obj` instead of `__obj`?

Comment: @AhmedMasud Note that it is a double underscore, so the *first* bullet of that paragraph applies and not the one you have cited.

Comment: @AhmedMasud That's not entirely accurate.  Identifiers that begin with two underscores, or an underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for *all* uses.  Identifiers that start with a single underscore followed by a lowercase letter are the ones reserved for filescope that you can overload (is that the correct term?) at local scope.